Does anyone know when's the next "site health discussion"?
Every now and then, the Stack Exchange sites get reviewed by users in terms of their performance (how users are growing, how's the quality of questions, measured through some indicators ...).
Does anyone happen to know when this will happen again for us?

Self-evaluations on beta-sites were running every 6 months.
However, the Community Team has shut down site self-evaluations in July 2015, because they were "not useful in their current form." So, it's not going to happen ever again (or, at least, not in the nearest future and not in the same form).
